# "Down and dirty" - what does it mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, expressions

> I am walking on the mud, down and dirty!

What does "down" mean?

Comment: Actually, I think you have to consider the entire phrase "down and dirty". My impression is that it conveys a feeling that the person does not often walk in the mud and is having fun. But, it could have different meanings depending on the context.

Comment: Is this something you read? Is it a song lyric? Do you have  a link that shows its use in context?

Comment: I forget where I read maybe on a post and that's the words shows below

Answer (score 2):

In your passage

> down and dirty

literally refers to the mud being on ground level ("down") and being "dirty" (since it is mud).

However, it is a play on a well know idiom: "[down and dirty](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/down%20and%20dirty)".

To get

> down and dirty

is to

> to get "down" to lowest level of detail *(the nitty gritty, the nuts and bolts)*

and

> to get "dirty"
>   get one's hands "dirty"

can mean to do something oneself, like a mechanic working on an engine gets into the details and gets their hands "dirty"

[image: here]

it can also mean to be unscrupulous, a cheater

> a "dirty" dog

Comment: 1>"can mean to do something oneself, like a mechanic working on an engine" hmm sorry I confused do you mean slang mean for "dirty"  Also,>2 to get "down and dirty" Is to get to "down" to lowest level and get to "dirty" btw, what is "get to down to lowest level" mean? Could you give me a example more than appreciate. 3 last, haha>what's down and dirty the idiom mean? what's the play ? I never hear of ))

Comment: @Maly have edited my answer, hopefully it will help you

Comment: Appreciated! there is one thing I confused "to get "down" to lowest level of detail (the nitty gritty, the nuts and bolts) " What do you mean the "nitty gritty, the nuts and bolts" ? Are they slang?

Comment: I just looked up " DOWN AND DIRTY" . It's showed up a RACE. So if you don't mind? would you tell me what's the different between the word " play " and " race" Thank you very much Mr Peter

Comment: "Nuts and bolts" means *something* is very basic since "[nuts and bolts](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/nuts+and+bolts)" hold things together (doesn't get more basic than that). Screws and glue also hold things together, but that's not a common expression...

Comment: Please post link to "play" and "race", I don't quite understand the reference